# How do you run a ONNX model on a GPU?

Tags: deep-learning, onnx, onnxruntime, onnx-coreml

I'm trying to run an ONNX model

```
import onnxruntime as ort
import onnxruntime.backend
model_path = "model.onnx"

#https://microsoft.github.io/onnxruntime/
ort_sess = ort.InferenceSession(model_path)


print( ort.get_device()  )
```

This prints out

```
cpu
```

How can I make it run on my GPU?  How can I confirm it's working?

Answer (score 22):

You probably installed the CPU version. Try uninstalling onnxruntime and install GPU version, like `pip install onnxruntime-gpu`.

Then:

```
>>> import onnxruntime as ort
>>> ort.get_device()
'GPU'
```

Comment: Single line version would be `python -c "import onnxruntime as ort;print(ort.get_device())" `

Answer (score 9):

get_device() command gives you the supported device to the onnxruntime.
For CPU and GPU there is different runtime packages are available.

Currently your onnxruntime environment support only CPU because you have installed CPU version of onnxruntime.

If you want to build onnxruntime environment for GPU use following simple steps.

**Step 1**: uninstall your current onnxruntime

```
>> pip uninstall onnxruntime
```

**Step 2**: install GPU version of onnxruntime environment

```
>>pip install onnxruntime-gpu
```

**Step 3**: Verify the device support for onnxruntime environment

```
>> import onnxruntime as rt
>> rt.get_device()
'GPU'
```

**Step 4**: If you still encounter **any issue please check with your cuda and CuDNN versions**, that must be compatible to each other.
Please refer this **link** [here](https://www.onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html) to understand about the version compatibility between cuda and CuDNN.

Answer (score 3):

your onnxruntime-gpu version should match your cuda and cudnn version,you can check their relations from the offical web site:
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html

Comment: I think this is the problem in my case. It looks like there's no support for CUDA 11.6 yet. Thanks.